# Ошибка: "отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам типы операндов std::ostream<<Record"

Tags: c++

Прошу помочь пишу программу чтобы с текстового файла записывало все данные в вектор, все вроде работает, но вывести на экран я этот вектор не могу, выдает ошибку "отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам типы операндов std::ostream

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include "locale.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <ostream.>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <allocators>
#include <clocale>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Record {
    string name;
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double e;
    double f;
    double g;
    double h;
    double i;
    double j;
    double k;
    double l;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Record> records;
    ifstream file("E:\\temperatury.txt");
    Record tmp;
    while (file >> tmp.name >> tmp.a >> tmp.b >> tmp.c >> tmp.d >> tmp.i >> tmp.f >> tmp.g >> tmp.h >> tmp.i >> tmp.j >> tmp.k >> tmp.l)
    records.push_back(tmp);
    if (file.bad()) {
        cout << "I/O error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (!file.eof()) {
        cout << "Invalid data\n";
        return 1;
    }

for (int z = 0; z < records.size(); z++) {
    cout << records[z] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Не обращайте внимание на все "include" просто пытался уже вставлять какие только возможно, здесь оставил вдруг пригодиться.

Если что текстовый документ выглядит так:

> Gdansk -2.5 -2.4 0.9 5.4 10.3 14.5 16.2 15.6 12.1 7.9 3.1 -0.5
>
> Gdynia -1.7 -2 0.9 5.2 10 14.5 16.8 16.4 12.8 8.3 3.7 0.5
>
> Warszawa -3.5 -2.7 1.5 7.9 13.3 16.8 18.2 17.4 13.3 8.5 3.1 -1.1
>
> NowyJork -0.6 0.5 4.9 10.6 16.5 21.5 24.5 23.8 19.5 13.5 7.9 2.2
>
> Bangkok 25.3 25.3 25.6 25.9 25.8 25.3 24.8 25.2 26.1 26.6 26.3 25.6

Comment: Вам нужно написать свой оператор для вывода `struct Record`. Сколько не подключайте все подряд - ну нет в библиотеке операторов вывода для всех типов, которые только могут придумать пользователи...

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте после объявления структуры

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const Record& r)
{
    return os << r.name << ": "
              << r.a << " " << r.b << " " << r.c << " "
              << r.d << " " << r.e << " " << r.f << " "
              << r.g << " " << r.h << " " << r.i << " "
              << r.j << " " << r.k << " " << r.l;
}
```